# What will cause an iPad (3rd gen) to crash on launch but work in the simulator?

Tags: ios, ipad-3

I got this rejection message from Apple.

> We found the app quit upon launch on the iPad (3rd Gen)

I have tested my iPhone app on both the 1st and 2nd generation iPads with no problem and used the simulator on retina mode to test the iPad 3rd generation. Apple did not provide me a crash log so before I go and fork out more money on another test device, here is my question.

Is there a list of items to check for that are known to crash the device but work in the simulator?  Could it be something with the @2x graphics at the retina resolution?

Comment: Perhaps it's not the device, but the OS. Does any of your (older) iPads run the latest OS? (5.1) I don't think it has anything to do with 2x graphics. Does your app include those, or just reuse 1x ones?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My iPad 2 was running 5.1 and now on 5.1.1 with no issues.  Currently using the 1x versions and runs fine on the device and sim.

Comment: Guess you will not know for sure until you can get an iPad 3... Anyone else?

Answer (score 2):

A few things that are different between a real device and the simulator:

1. less memory on the device; the iPad 3 will use @2x images, thus it will use double memory for images as compared to the iPad 1/2;
2. device is slower (except for OpenGL and other graphical tasks that are optimized): at startup an app has got 5 seconds max to complete `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, otherwise it will be killed;
3. device file system is case sensitive: if you refer to a resource by a name that does not respect uppercase/lowercase, the device will complain.

For sure there are many more. Furthermore there is a general difference of simulator and device, so that you cannot fully trust the simulator, but I understand this does not help you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great list Sergio.  This at least gives me places to look.

Comment: All good points, but he **did** test on a real device (iPad 1 & 2). Perhaps point #1 (memory) is a clue. Regarding #2, In my experience Simulator is usually faster **including** OpenGL (unless you do something **really** aimed at the device GPU and very inefficient on desktop) Most of the time is about raw power.

Comment: @ranReloaded: you are right about point 2 and 3, I was just in brainstorming mode... :-) about performance, I guarantee you that the simulator on my MacBook Pro is way slower than an iPad 1 when doing Open GL... but you are right in that it depends on the hw you are running the simulator on...

Comment: In my case, 2011 21 inch iMac runs circles around Retina iPod Touch